# Dropdown in WEbdriverIO with JS

Tags: javascript

In java with dropdowns we used  to use select class and or save all the weblements in List collection and iterate thru and get the option we want and click on it. I wanna know we can do the same with JS in WebdriverIO. I am new to JS and WBIO and struggling to follow the same  structure in JS with WebdriverIO.

```
<select id = "myId"
  <option class = "Field1" value = "check1">Text1</options
  <option class = "Field2" value = "check2">Text2</options
  <option class = "Field3" value = "check3">Text3</options
```

and so on.. I want to save all option values or texts and loop trough and get matching text in my method parameter. Please advice

Comment: Can you share what you've done in Javascript so far?

Comment: Hi. I have created a scratch method. chooseIdType( idType) {